# how to call image in jquery in octobercms?

Tags: octobercms

i have jquery plugin called "jquery social stream".In jquery there are two options

```
iconPath:'assets/images/dcsns-dark/icons',
    imagePath:'assets/images/dcsns-dark/icons'
```

but still icon and image does not appear

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question , all you have to do is to add |theme
So the path will be "assets/images/photo.png"|theme . That's all

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it is working now.
Will you please tell me that since this jquery plugin has php code as facebook.php,rss.php and twitter.php but octobercms does not use php code in pages how to use these files please tell me?

Comment: Actually you can use php files in plugins, but in themes you'll have to convert the php code the october way.
My opinion if you use an external php files like some class you want to use to generate a random barcode for example you can put the php file of the class in a plugin and then use it in your theme page and you can use it normally.
If you didn't get it tell me and I'll provide you a full explanation with code.

Comment: thank you for your reply.sorry i was late because of health issues.i tried that php code.actually i have purchased it from codecanyon but client need it to work in octobercms.so it just wasted my money.if you can help i will give the whole code what i have purchased from codecanyon.